# Redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

the url of my site is: http://www.mysite.com/site

and I want that requests as http://www.mysite.com/[ANY_NAME]

are redirected to http://www.mysite.com/site

How do I change the htaccess?
Thank's :)

Comment: Have you tried something? Show it!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site.* # if its not /site
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/site [R=301,L]
```

if 'site' is a directory, you have to add a slash `/` after 'site'